# Question of the Week #37

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #37 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [How to know if your computer is hit by a dnschanger virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/446315/how-to-know-if-your-computer-is-hit-by-a-dnschanger-virus)

Perhaps could append how the computer got infected as well.

**Pro**:

1. Get to understand how a virus affects your computer.
2. Preparing people for when a future attempt occurs.

**Con**:

1. Servers took down, might no longer be relevant / valuable.
2. Might be more Security.SE material.

Comment: I like this one, because it hooks into current events

Answer (score 3):

### [Can AVI files contain a virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/445366/can-avi-files-contain-a-virus)

Some people might not be aware of this, as well as sites that want you to dowload codecs; awareness of this is pretty crucial, which is why I think this could also make up for a good QotW.

Many people assume such containers are safe, but it's never too late for a zero-day exploit.